# What is a standard procedure while parallelising a serial code

Tags: c++, documentation, development-methodologies

I have a C++ serial code which simulates a physics algorithm. The C++ code is serially optimised. What is the standard procedure and documentation that is followed while parallelising the code or for GPU acceleration? I am accelerating the code on Nvdia Tesla K40 & Intel Knights Landing cluster.

Comment: [Hint: Software Engineering Stack Exchange... expect research before asking](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7826/31260)

Comment: The act of writing code doesn't follow "standard procedures."  There are well-known and well-understood tools, techniques and expertise, but no "standard procedures."  Sorry, but you'll have to learn this stuff the hard way, like all the rest of us.  It's not like screwing in a light bulb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is, indeed, a standard first-step to this task.

Measure first.

[List of performance analysis tools on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools)

This will give you an overview of what are the most intensive computations, the most memory I/O and/or latency-intensive computations, whether these computations are integer-heavy or floating-point heavy. Also, try to find out whether the code uses SIMD.

---

When prioritizing what to parallelize, there will be conflicts between two preferences:

- Optimize the heaviest things first, because of Pareto principle (or, 80-20 rule)
- Optimize the easiest-to-optimize things first, because, it's easy and it's doable without costing too much time/effort.

It is hard to say how to choose the middle ground between these preferences.

---

Check if you're allowed to use OpenMP. It is probably the easiest way to enable multithread parallelization.

---

Check for, and eliminate, race conditions that will cause code to give wrong result or crash.

---

Comment: Lastly, it is entirely possible that the data dependencies are such that the algorithm simply *cannot* be parallelized, and the whole thing has to be redesigned from scratch with a *different*, parallel algorithm.

Comment: Best possible answer for an almost unanswerable question. Surely not what the OP expected.

Comment: I admit I jumped the gun. I did not realize the question is focused on GPU parallelization. That was certainly not something that CPU-based approaches could apply to. So, few or none of my advice would apply. I think OP could choose John Forkosh's answer.

Comment: @rwong this is what I exactly needed. I am doing this with no guidance, so I needed some form of validation, though I did mention GPU, I also mentioned Intel Knights Landing. So giving advice of measure first and that Wikipedia article, really helped.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about "standard", per se, but if you're building an nvidia-gpu-based box, look at the cuda libraries, https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-accelerated-libraries In particular, you mention "physics algorithm", which often involves lots of matrix calculations, whereby https://developer.nvidia.com/arrayfire might be most helpful.

Rather than taking your existing codebase and parallelizing it piece-by-piece, you may need to high-level re-analyze your algorithm(s) in terms of the available gpu accelerated libraries, and then decompose your problem in such a way as to make the best possible use of these library components.